# Bootstrap Row Structure

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In Twitter Bootstrap the default row structure is 12 columns wide. Given the following code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
            Hello-1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
            Hello-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
            Hello-3
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
            Hello-4
    </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

There is a default amount of space between the columns, but I want to display the columns nearer to each other. Is there any way to do this with Bootstrap classes?

Comment: Did you try to change `lg` to `md` ?

Comment: Yes.! i try it but i think md not for div size. md is use when screen is resized

Comment: no md is not working.

Comment: @ofiris, no they don't. 1-12 define width (as a fraction of 12) and xs-lg define at which screen widths to show them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
There is three more classes. 
1- offset
2- push
3- pull

offset is use for margin-left:%
push is use for left:%
pull is use for right:%
```

you can use it to make your 12 grid to get and remove the distance between them .

for example : from your code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-3">
            Hello-1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
            Hello-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-1 ">
            Hello-3
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
            Hello-4
    </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to remove padding and margin from the divs ???
add css

.div-left
{float:left; }

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="div-left">
            Hello-1
    </div>
    <div class="div-left">
            Hello-2
    </div>
    <div class="div-left">
            Hello-3
    </div>
    <div class="div-left">
            Hello-4
    </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Heres example http://www.bootply.com/126135

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ Hope this link will help you you need to assign grid to your divs as well. Width will vary according to the screen resolution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much would you like to alter the gap. You can go ahead and customize bootstrap via website or compile it from source.

Attribute you want to customize is `grid-gutter-width` that is set by default to 30px;

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

I have posted video on youtube how to do it with the source (tailored for mac). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSkBLoz2XmU

Answer (score 0):

LESS: Line 305 on variables.less there is a variable called @grid-gutter-width which you can reduce: Bootstrap does @grid-gutter-width/2 to calculate actual column padding.

With CSS you would have to edit the file manually, or override it with an extra class.